# R for-loop vector 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,..,10,

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I have been trying to make vector `1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,...,10` in R with a for-loop. But my code doesn't seem to work...

```
vector <- c()
vector[1]<-1
k <- 1
for (i in 1:10){
for (j in 1:10)
if (j<=i){
vector[j+1] = vector[i]+k    
}
k <- k+1 }
```

Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is best done without any loops:   `rep(1:10, 1:10)`
But if you really *must* do it with nested loops, this would work:

```
vector = c()
for(i in 1:10) { 
    for(j in 1:i) {
       vector = c(vector, i) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
vector=rep(1:10,1:10)
```